# regex match more than one zero

Tags: php, regex

As the title suggests I need a way to match more than one zero at the end of a number `$`.

```
100 //match
10 // no match
4000 // match
340 // no match
74003 //no match
```

I'm using php if that matters.

Attempts:
`0+(?!(0))$`
`0[0-9]+$`

Comment: You want to match the whole number given it has more than one zero or just the zeros in the numbers when theres more than one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$regex = "/0{2,}$/";
var_dump(preg_match($regex, "4000"));

php> $regex = "/0{2,}$/"

php> preg_match($regex, "100")

php> echo preg_match($regex, "100")
1
php> echo preg_match($regex, "10")
0
php> echo preg_match($regex, "4000")
1
php> echo preg_match($regex, "340")
0
php> echo preg_match($regex, "74003")
0
php>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number must start with a non-zero:

```
/^[1-9]+00+$/
```

If the number can start with a zero:

```
/^\d*00+$/
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to check if 2 last digits are 0 you may use

```
if($number % 100 == 0){
    //0 will be here too, if you need not it try to add (and $number!=0)
}
```

regexp will be bit overkill here